# How can I insulate gas range down vent to prevent cold air blowing through?

Tags: insulation, vent, kitchen-island, cooktops

I have a Jennair gas cooktop in the island of my kitchen on the second floor of my house.  It has two burners on either side with a downdraft vent/fan in the middle.  We are in the middle of an unusual cold snap in South Texas and standing in front of the range I can feel a significant cold draft coming up from it, and when I touch the grate covering it, it is really cold.  How do I insulate this or prevent cold air from coming up through here.

My understanding is this only vents out when you turn on the fan in the event of smoke while cooking, so how do I prevent outside air coming in?

Comment: Have you checked the outdoor damper on the vent to see if it's blocked from closing?